# How to fix CSS when you want to stack cards one top of the other when viewed on Mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

When I viewed on mobile phone, I noticed that the three small cards in Red, Green, and Yellow, are not stacking on top of the other. For example, on phone you can see that the Red and Green are side by side and not stacking. How can we change the CSS so that we can make the Green card below the red, and the yellow card bellow the green, when viewed on mobile only?

I tried to stack the cards, using something like this (below), but I am not sure if that's the proper way of doing this.

```
    @media (max-width: px)  {
    .flex-container {
}
}
```

Comment: You will receive more helpful responses if you include what you have tried, including HTML, and either a snippet embedded in the question or a link to a JSFiddle or Codepen etc.

Answer (score 1):

solution 1:
change class on html file from "col-sm-4 mainColumnCardWrapper"
to "col-md-4 col-sm-12 mainColumnCardWrapper"
Give him three items

OR

solution 2:
add this on css file:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .mainColumnCardWrapper {
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can add for colored box this class `col-xs-12.col-sm-4.mainColumnCardWrapper`

This will cause the boxes to be at 100% viewport for viewport <767px.

Comment: I am sorry but where would I added that? In the CSS?

Comment: No, you add class for <div> (with colored box).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `display:none;` for pc version method in your CSS. And then, you need to pc and mobile version HTML/CSS.

You can [read](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) this tutorial for better understand